# A morphism to projective $n$-space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra of finite dimension $n$. What is a natural way to define an explicit "inclusion" morphism $Spec(A) \to \mathbb{P}^n$ realizing $Spec(A)$ as a finite set of points in $\mathbb{P}^n$?

Hoping to reduce to an affine situation, let's write $A=k[a_1,\ldots,a_n]$ and $\mathbb{P}^n$ as a union of the $D_+(x_i)\cong \mathbb{A}^n$. I have no idea how to define the corresponding homomorphisms of rings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is a $k$-álgebra of dimension $n$, you can pick $n$ elements $a_1,\dots,a_n$ in $A$ that generate $A$ as an algebra (for example, a basis of $A$), and define a surjective map of algebras $f:k[x_1,\dots,x_n]\to A$ such that $f(x_i)=a_i$ for all $i$. This map induces a map $\phi:\operatorname{Spec}A\to\operatorname{Spec}k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ which is a closed immersion, which you can compose with an inclusion into a projective space.